# DatePicker not responding to user input from Keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have a DatePicker in my activity. It works fine except when the user enters the date via the keypad and does not use the + or - buttons to change date.
The date returned when the user edits via keyboard is always what is the DatePicker is  initialized with.
When debug I notice the onDateChanged() callback is never called except when the date is change using the buttons.

Answer (score 9):

Yep, I meet this issue too. The datepicker will save the change only if you remove the focus from the active edittext. So you have to run "mDatePicker.clearFocus();" before you get the date from it.

Comment: Thanks. but I decided to replace that part with a date picker dialog instead. but i checked the solution you suggested and it works so thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Look at this solution...

```
DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
dp.clearChildFocus(getCurrentFocus());
int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
int month = dp.getMonth();
int year = dp.getYear();
```

... using "clearFocus" the DatePicker won't completely save user changes.